# Getting group member and discussion thread

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I've been playing around with something I was hoping I could contribute to the example archive, but I was struggling with extracting the members of a group, and also accessing a thread in a discussion board. From what I gather, discussion boards aren't accessible through Graph calls, but I was hoping someone had any good ideas.

As for the group members, I can only seem to get one by using the following:

```
Dictionary<string, object> apiParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
FacebookApp tmpApp = new FacebookApp();
apiParams.Add("access_token", tmpApp.Session.AccessToken);

JsonObject groupMembers = app.Api("/" + groupUID + "/members", apiParams) as JsonObject;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about which rights I had...;)